# perldoc error: No documentation file

Tags: perl

I usually document my perl code using POD syntax, normally I can read the documentation using:

```
perldoc myscript.pl
```

where myscript.pl is the perl script I wrote with the POD inside.

For example if **myscript.pl** contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

print 'hello world';

=head1 NAME

My Script name

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Description of My Script

=cut
```

and execute: **perldoc myscript.pl** I got this:

```
MYSCRIPT(1)           User Contributed Perl Documentation          MYSCRIPT(1)



NAME
       My Script name

DESCRIPTION
       Description of My Script



perl v5.18.2                      2016-03-15                       MYSCRIPT(1)
```

Now I found that in some systems I got the following error:

```
$ perldoc myscript.pl
No documentation found for "myscript.pl".
```

Anyone have an idea why is this happening? Could be a missing module or software package? Anything else?

Comment: Try things like `type perldoc`, make sure the script exist in the current directory or in $PATH. What Perl versions are involved?

Comment: perldoc works perfectly, that is not the issue ... perl 5.18.2 works ok on Mac OS but the same version fails on Debian so I don't think it's related to the version either

Comment: Where is the script on Mac OS X?  Where is the script on Debian?  What is your current directory when you run `perldoc myscript.pl` on Mac OS X and on Debian?

Comment: in both cases (OS X and Debian) the script is in the current working directory

Answer (score 2):

If you consult the man page for perldoc itself; `man perldoc` you read:

```
 "perldoc" also searches directories specified by the 
 "PERL5LIB" (or "PERLLIB" if "PERL5LIB" is not defined) and
 "PATH" environment variables.  (The latter is so that embedded 
 pods for executables, such as "perldoc" itself,are available.)
```

So you see, the usual places that libraries of modules can be found are searched but also directories specified in your **$PATH** environment variable.  The latter might come as a surprise but as the man page explains, how else is going to check for POD in home-grown scripts.

Your question is really dependant on your environment so, I can't say anything authoritative, but I would bet that in some places (ie some machines) your **$PATH** includes **"."** - the current directory - for convenience but on other machines,  **"."** is excluded from **$PATH** on security grounds.

Failing that, you can get a running commentary on where perldoc is looking for the POD by using the **-D** CLI option:

```
$ perldoc -D myscript.pl
Ending switch processing.  Args are [myscript.pl] with 0 errors.
Pagers: /usr/bin/sensible-pagermorelesspgviewcat/usr/bin/perldoc => Pod::Perldoc v3.23

Formatter class Pod::Perldoc::ToTerm version 3.23 successfully loaded!
Will format with the class Pod::Perldoc::ToTerm
Searching for myscript.pl
Looking for myscript.pl in /usr/bin /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gn
u/perl/5.20.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20
/usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20 /usr/share/perl/5.20
/usr/local/lib/site_perl . /opt/perl6/share/perl6/site/bin /opt/perl6/bin
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin
No documentation found for "myscript.pl".
$
```

I deliberately chose "myscript.pl" because I don't have such a script.  You see clearly everywhere it's looking - this should reveal where the problem is. Finally, finally, you can use `-F` to explicitly state what file to get the POD out of - this can be used to see if the problem is the POD in the file itself:  `perldoc -F ./myscript.pl`

Comment: I've added **.** on the **$PATH** environment variable but the behavior is the same ... Also, in both environments **.** (the current directory) is included in the defined library path

Comment: I've updated my answer with another thing to try - the "-D" option

Comment: there's clearly a bug then, according to the output you posted, it looked for myscript.pl in **.** (the current directory) but it couldn't find it, right?

Comment: In my case yes - I have "." in my path - but that's irrelevant.  I'm suggesting *you* run this and study the output carefully and check that the directory that has (the real) "myscript.pl" (on your machine) is one of the directories checked by perldoc.

Comment: I think is relevant, because I have a similar output (with the current directory included) but it couldn't find the script AND the script is in the current directory

Comment: post output of this __perldoc -D myscript.pl 2>&1 | perl -nE '/Looking/ && say join("\n", split " ")'__

Comment: Looking
for
myscript.pl
in
/usr/bin
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20
/usr/share/perl/5.20
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
.
/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin

Comment: I've edited the answer again to add one more option to eliminate (or prove) the problem being with the POD itself.  If that doesn't help, I'm out of ideas! :-)

Comment: that doesn't work (I think -d is not useful in this case) ... have you tried the command with an existent myscript.pl? does it work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

For those that stumble across this (like me):

```
pod2man ./myscript.pl | groff -man -T utf8
```

...maybe.  If you want all the glorious man-page formatting.  Otherwise, maybe `pod2text`?